# bluetooth socket hangs after transferring 40 characters

Tags: bluetooth, rfcomm

I am trying to get a Bluetooth Communication link established between a STM32 Bluetooth Device and a Class 1 Bluetooth Dongle connected on the beaglebone black.

The Device is getting detected, pairing and everything!.

The idea is to use SPP and Exchange data between the STM module and the Bluetooth Dongle connected to the beaglebone Black.

Here's my code what's used to establish the communication.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc addr = { 0 };
    int s, status;
    char dest[18] = "00:80:E1:B3:28:DE";
    char buf[2048] = { 0 };
    // allocate a socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // set the connection parameters (who to connect to)
    addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    str2ba( dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr );

    // connect to server
    status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

   //  send a message
    if( status == 0 ) {
    while(1){


    status = recv(s, buf,1,0);
    if( status  > 0 ) {
        printf("\n\nreceived [%s]\n", buf);
    }

    }
    }

    if( status < 0 ) perror("\n\nuh oh");

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

What happens is after transferring 40 character ( on the module, not the host)  the recv() doesn't output anything. The Code Has to be stopped (Ctrl + C) and then restarted.

Is there some buffer that has to be cleared or something resetted after every 40 chars?

I tried the same code with a HC-05 MOdule, Got the same problem.

Anyone with expreience with rfcomm and socket code?

Comment: Please show your sending function and the data it is trying to send. If the `recv` does not return then it means that it does not have any data to receive.

Comment: The data is sent using the putty terminal to the STM Module. The data is then wirelessly transmitted to the Beagebone Black which is fitted with the Bluetooth dongle.